# Save Changes to File Without reloading Page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Right now I have an HTML textarea that gets its contents from a text file. What I want to be able to do is allow the user to edit the file in the textarea and when they press a button, the changes get pushed to the file without having to reload the whole page.

I understand this can't be done with javascript alone because its a client side language, but I was thinking this could maybe be done with AJAX somehow? I don't have much experience with AJAX, so that might not work.

I want to stay away from websockets for the sake of simplicity for what I have to do.

Below is my PHP textarea code:

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen($file, 'a+');

    echo "<textarea id='demo'>";
    // go through each line in the file, print its contents.
    while(!feof($myfile)) {
          echo fgets($myfile);
    }
          echo "</textarea>";
?>
```

Comment: Sure, you simply attach a handler to the click event of the "save" button which takes the value of the text area and sends an ajax request to the server. There you have a "save" script (maybe in php or whatever language) that receives the payload and saves it.

Comment: @arkascha Okay, I will look into that and give it a try. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without refreshing the whole page you can update the textarea using jquery ajax. When you click `save changes` on index.php(in my example here), we get the value of the textarea by its `id="demo"` and send it update.php. In update.php, we use `fwrite()` to clear all existing text and write the new content we get from our `textarea` to it, and display the new text like we did in `index.php`.

So this is `index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>TextArea Lesson</title>
             <style>
                 div{
                     margin:0 auto 0;
                     width:400px;
                     height:300px;
                 }
                 #demo{
                     margin-left:5px;
                     width:390px;
                     height:200px;               
                 }
             </style>       
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
            <form method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Ajax Update Text Area</legend>
        <?php
            $myfile = fopen('test.txt', 'r');
              echo "<textarea id='demo'>";
            // go through each line in the file, print its contents.
            while(!feof($myfile)) {
              echo fgets($myfile);
            }
              echo "</textarea><br>";
        ?>
                    <input type="submit" id="save" value="Save changes" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"
                  integrity="sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk="
                  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    //when you click save changes, we get its id="save"
    //and prevent default submission    
    $(document).on("click", "#save", function(e){   
            e.preventDefault();
            //get the textarea data bu its id="demo"
            var textdata = $('#demo').val();
            mydata= 'testdata='+textdata;
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:mydata,
                url:'update.php',
                success:function(data) {                
                    if(data){
                      alert('Saved!');
                      $("#demo").html(data);//load data from update.php
                    }else{
                      alert('Update failed');
                    }
                  }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

`Update.php`:

```
<?php
$data_to_write = $_POST['testdata'];
$file_path = 'test.txt';
$file_handle = fopen($file_path, 'w'); 
fwrite($file_handle, $data_to_write);
fclose($file_handle);
$myfile = fopen('test.txt', 'r');
 while(!feof($myfile)) {
          echo fgets($myfile);
    }
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

And `test.txt`:

> The big quick brown black fox jumps over a lazy dog.

I hope this may help you. Note: This is just a working code and for learning purpose only. So security checking and data validation is not ensured.

Comment: If I want to make update.php universal (not hardcode 'test.txt') and I have a variable in index.php, say $file that contains the file path. Would I pass that variable through ajax as well?

Comment: Yes of course, it's possible. `var filepath='getfilepathfromform';` and  `'testdata='+textdata+'&filepath='+filepath;` And in update.php, `$file_path=$_POST['filepath'];`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a couple of easy ways of doing it.

1. you can have a hidden iframe.
   when the person click on the submit form, you call a function that takes the value of your field send it to a form in your hidden frame, and submit the form using JavaScript.
2. you can use XMLHttpRequest(); 
   create a php page that takes the data passed to it.
   call the page using XMLHttpRequest(); sending the data from the form.

method 2 is more elegant.